# How to load a different layout in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I have 2 layout files.
Layout-1
Layout-2

The route `/one` is the starting point which loads the `Layout-1`, but now if I click on a link `/two` it gets me the file, but with `Layout-1`, instead i want, if i hit `/two`, `Layout-2` should be loaded.

If i refresh the page, i get the correct thing coz that time i hit the server directly. So is there any way from angular to specify which layout file to load from Server.

Thanks.

Comment: use ng-view with $routeprovider to configure routes bunch of examples are available online

Comment: i couldn't find any example where in i can have templates rendered inside different LAYOUT files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the problem solved using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? I'm facing the exact same issue currently. I have index.html and index-dashboard.html with each lots of templates inside and I'm not able to switch the layout

Comment: yeah, it would be great if you can post sample code how did you implement the UI Router that load a different layout.

Comment: Hey Aamir would you mind sharing what solved the problem? Accepting your own answer without even answering is not really helpfull.

Comment: There is a full demonstration on youtube by Tim Kindberg here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqJRoh8MnBo

Comment: @Aamir Shah I would really appreciate if you could post your code that solved your problem. I am facing the same issue, googled a lot but could not find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Loading new layout template means loading new html embedded with new javascript and css files. 
This is equal to redirecting page to new location. You can use  `$window.location.href="new/layout/template"`. Read [angularjs developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If it stands for client side routing then you should use [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider) to write a route for this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/one', {templateUrl: 'tmpl1.html'})
    .when('/two', {templateUrl: 'tmpl2.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/one'});
});
```

It will allow you to define separate template and controller for another url/action

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1WfIY1OCryuC6bDvWSFK?p=preview) I made a working example of how it work.

If it is about serverside routing then read [manual](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and use it like this:

```
match 'two' => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm doing. But tmpl1.html tmpl2.html are the partials. What i want is to load these partials in a different layout...can u help me in that... thanks

Comment: Look in plnkr example. It will load corresponding templates (is it same as partials?) into the div marked with `ng-view`. Main layout is in index.html. According to this example I'm not sure what do you want to change?

Comment: Do you want to change index.html rather than tmpl*.thml files?

Comment: I guess u didn't get my question. I have two layout files and many partials. Both the layout files have ng-view. What i want is to load a particular route (say /two) in Layout file - 2.

Comment: Than you should use serverside routing.

Comment: already tried, but that will work only if i refresh the page, the problem is: I current have Layout-1 loaded, when i make request  using angular it gets me the file but loads that in ng-view of Layout-1, but what i want is Layout-2

Comment: It would be really nice if you could give more details on your problem from the beginning. Most probably your links looks like `/#whatever` when they should point to `/whatever` so that browser will create request to server to load another layout.

Comment: i have a layout file as: <div id="layout1">.......</div> and then ng-view, similarly <div id="layout2">.......</div> and then ng-view, so my question is how to change the layout files based on the routing from angular

Comment: Provide a plunkr with the layout html, because this still does not make things clear

Comment: @AamirShah you can have only one layout with ng-view to load only one template for your application so you can't change it without reloading page. However inside layout you can have multiply ng-inlclude directives to create needed views nesting.